# Prove $\sqrt[5]{y} - \sqrt[5]{z} < \sqrt[5]{y-z}$ for all $y > z > 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can this be proven with the knowledge that if $f'(x) \leq 0$ on $(y,z)$, then $f$ is a decreasing function.

Starting out with $f(x) = x^{1/5} - (x - 1)^{1/5}$, and using the endpoints of $1$ and $\frac{y}{z}$, I don't see where to go from here...?

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b\ge0$ we know that
$$
a^5+b^5\le a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5=(a+b)^5
$$
or
$$
\sqrt[5]{a^5+b^5}\le a+b.
$$
Now if $0\le x\le y$ set $a=\sqrt[5]x$ and $b=\sqrt[5]{y-x}$ to find
$$
\sqrt[5]{y}\le \sqrt[5]x+\sqrt[5]{y-x}
$$
from which the claimed inequality follows.